# Jquery Change One Element's Class When Clicking on Another

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to modify a `UL` when an `LI` is clicked using jQuery. I'm sure this must be quite simple but I can't for the life of me get my head around it!

This is for a simple filter menu that uses a `max-height` property so when you hover over it the `max-height` changes and the menu shows. The problem I'm having is that I need the menu to reset when an `LI` is clicked as at the moment the menu is getting in the way on mobile devices.

The output is powered by a Wordpress plugin so I can't change or alter the structure which isn't helping.

The HTML structure is something along the lines of:

```
<div class="alm-filter">
  <ul>
    <li class="alm-filter--radio"><a href="">First menu item</a></li>
    <li class="alm-filter--radio"><a href="">Second menu item</a></li>
    <li class="alm-filter--radio"><a href="">Third menu item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any my css is as follows:

```
.alm-filter ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 271px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  max-height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.alm-filter ul.small {
max-height: 60px;
}

.alm-filter ul:hover {
  max-height: 317px;
}

.alm-filter li {
  text-align: left;
}

.alm-filter li a {
  color: #104530;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  background-color: #B7C6C1;
}

.alm-filter li a:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

I tried a variety of Jquery snippets that I found on here, the last one that looked the simplest to implement was:

```
$('.alm-filter--radio').click(function(){ 
$('.alm-filter ul').toggleClass('small');  
});
```

The hover effect works fine however on smaller devices when a user click a menu link the menu stays open which is a little confusing. Ideally what I'd like is for the menu to close when a link is clicked.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

James

Comment: $('.alm-filter--radio').click(function(){
 $('.alm-filter').hide();
});

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately that doesn't seem to have had any affect. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove **.alm-filter ul:hover** from your css and change the javascript to

```
function resetHeight() {
    $('.alm-filter ul').css('max-height', '');  
}

$('.alm-filter--radio').hover(function() {
    $('.alm-filter ul').css('max-height', '317px'); 
}, resetHeight).click(resetHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work either, the hover effect no longer works if I add this code snippet.

Comment: Hi, it worked for me. I created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Aqid/qm80nh45/1/

Comment: That's great thanks! I just needed to add the code to the footer rather than the header, worked like a charm!